# Why won't Python math work with a variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
UseCounter = 1

UseCounter + 1
```

I think that `UseCounter` should be 2.

But if i print it, it's still 1.

Comment: did you mean `UseCounter += 1`? In your code, you do not *assign* the result of `UseCounter + 1` to anything; `UseCounter` won't update automagically

Comment: No? I just wanna set UseCounter to 1

Comment: his suggestion is correct

Comment: `UseCounter + 1` doesn't do anything, by itself anyway

Comment: UseCounter += just throws Errors all over the Place

Comment: I suggest you read a Python tutorial to understand how to work with mathematical expressions. In particular, you need to learn about assignment operators.

Comment: cannot reproduce. `+=` works fine. besides, `var += 1` it is just syntactic sugar for `var = var + 1`.

Comment: @ErsterImChat If you need help with particular errors, I suggest that you google them to see what other people already did to solve them. If you still need help, then you should post a new question with the exact code that causes the errors along with the entire error message.

Comment: @MrFuppes it's not just syntactic sugar; you can implement `__iadd__` to specifically handle `+=`.

Comment: Edit: Was a fault of Mine. Everithing works now.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks, wasn't aware that this assignemt operator actually calls a specific dunder method - still learning something here :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't added 1 to UseCounter and it still has the value 1.If you want to add 1 to it you must write it like:

```
UseCounter = 1    
UseCounter += 1
print(UseCounter)
```

Comment: It will help future visitors a lot if you provide a complete example. This one line by itself causes an error. Of course, those of us that know python well understand the context and what is needed, but a newbie will need a bit more details.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add equals on it.

```
UseCounter += 1
```